# How to split a python dataframe based on new line characters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe in which a column contains paragraphs of text. I wanted to explode the dataframe into separate columns by splitting the paragraphs of text into newlines. The paragraph of text may contain multiple new lines.

Example dataframe:

```
Current output:
A
foo bar
foo bar\nfoo bar
foo bar
foo bar

Desired output:

   A         B                                                      
0 foo bar                                                  
1 foo bar   foo bar                                                 
2 foo bar                                                  
3 foo bar
```

I have tried using this:

```
df.A.str.split(expand=True))
```

But it is splitting at every whitespace not "/n" as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) you should be able to specify the delimiter to split on as the (optional) parameter of the `split` method `par`, otherwise it will split on whitespaces only:

*"String or regular expression to split on. If not specified, split on whitespace."*

Therefore you may do the following to achive the newline-splitting feature:

```
df.A.str.split(pat="\n", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the pattern on which to split the string as an argument to [`series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). Here is a complete reproducible example that works on Windows systems:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo bar', 
                         'foo bar\nfoo bar',
                         'foo bar',
                         'foo bar']})

df.A.str.split(pat='\n', expand=True)
```

```
    0           1
0   foo bar     None
1   foo bar     foo bar
2   foo bar     None
3   foo bar     None
```

For a platform-independent solution, I would do something similar to @ThePyGuy's answer, but with [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), because this method will recognize line boundaries from various systems.

```py
df.A.apply(str.splitlines).apply(pd.Series).fillna('')
```

Comment: Hmm, it does work for me (Python 3.9.5, pandas 1.2.5). What exactly happens when you try it?

Comment: It doesn't split

Comment: I've added a complete example. Does that run this way on your system?

Comment: No.. It doesn't

Comment: I've added a platform-independent solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following: Use python's native `str.split` apply on the column, then apply `pd.Series` to create multiple columns out of it.

```py
>>> df.A.apply(lambda x: x.split(r'\n')).apply(pd.Series).fillna('')

         0        1
0  foo bar         
1  foo bar  foo bar
2  foo bar         
3  foo bar
```

Finally, you can just rename the columns.