# How to split a python dataframe into rows based on new line characters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, newline

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520893/how-to-split-a-python-dataframe-based-on-new-line-characters), I wanted to explode the dataframe into separate columns by splitting the values into newlines as separate rows. The values may contain multiple new lines.

Example Dataframe:

```
Fruit  |  Store
----------------
Apple  |  Querty
Banana |  Mouz\nVazhai
Grapes |  Angoor\nRangoon
```

I want this dataframe to be split into the following:

```
Fruit  |  Store
----------------
Apple  |  Querty
Banana |  Mouz
Banana |  Vazhai
Grapes |  Angoor
Grapes |  Rangoon
```

Is there any solution to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

First split values to lists and then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.assign(Store = df['Store'].str.split(r'\n')).explode('Store')
```

Comment: All this code does is convert that text into a list and place it in a new column. I wanted to create the same row again with just the Store values as unique.