# Converting strings consisting of multiple lines in a pandas dataframe to one line

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a bunch of strings stored in a field called `bio` in a df called `df_info`. Some of them have multiple lines in their strings as such:

```
Journalist and Reporter 
Baltimore Girl Living In A Nashville World 
Surviving Off Of Target Pick Up, Coffee & My Fave Playlists ☕️  #Debtfreeliving
```

Others are already one line like such:

```
Professional basketball blogger and dog mom
```

I am trying to get all of the fields in `bio` to be one readable text line so that the first example looks like this:

```
Journalist and Reporter  Baltimore Girl Living In A Nashville World Surviving Off Of Target Pick Up, Coffee & My Fave Playlists ☕️  #Debtfreeliving
```

I've tried using previous answers to similar questions like this:

```
df_info.bio = str.join(" ", df_info.bio.splitlines())
```

But it tells me: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`

Comment: Are you using `pandas`? A `Series` is not a standard python object type.

Comment: Yeah I believe I'm using `pandas`

Comment: are you looking for `pd.Series.str.split("\n")`? [How to split a python dataframe based on new line characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68520893/10197418)

Comment: @FObersteiner - Maybe? What would that look like in the context of my script?

Comment: something like `df_info.bio = df_info.bio.str.split("\n").str.join(" ")` to split on newline, then join with a space. So basically you're looking for the `str` accessor.

Comment: You can see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for how you can improve this question, and future pandas related questions~